# Failed to apt upgrade on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS "redirection loop encountered"

Tags: apt, 18.04

I get the error below every time I try to `sudo apt upgrade` after running `sudo apt update` on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

```
E: Failed to fetch http://62.8.79.10:80/data/0624c5a5c5ab9d20/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-7/gcc-7_7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb
 Redirection loop encountered
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Which command do you get this error on?  If on `sudo apt update` then you have a bad entry in sources (I'd check them regardless; as the 'Wananchi Group' address may be legit for you, but I'd really wonder why?).  It would be better if you'd provided the specific command, and you copied the error from (it looks like update, but your text implies upgrade)..  Either way I'd suggest checking your sources (`/etc/apt/sources.list` & sources.list.d/)

Comment: This was not a duplicate. But the answer given by Ade Malsasa Akbar below worked perfectly to solve this.
Thank you for attempt to help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

That sort of error is usually caused by bad internet access or a missing package on the destination server. A simple solution for this is changing your mirror to another one.

- Go to **menu > Software & Updates**
- See the section *Download from*: Server for your country
- Click that button > Other... > select another server under the name of your country > click <kbd>Choose Server</kbd>
- If asked, click **Reload** and wait until it's finished.

Now go back to your failed installation and continue it.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me. Thank you Ade Malsasa Akbar

Comment: If the answer worked for you, you should accept it, or at least +1 (upvote) the answer (commenting if it won't let you accept it; as it can always be re-opened if that is required)

Comment: this didn't work for me.